# Should words like zakat, hadith, halal, haram start with capital letters?

Tags: support

Many users use capital letters when writing these words. Should I keep them the way they are when editing questions?

Answer (score 3):

Way I see it, these are common nouns so I do not see a need to captilize them.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Nowadays they can be deemed as common nouns, so it is not necessary to capitalize them.

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem with writing those words in lower case. But if a good or better transliteration is present I wouldn't edit it. But maybe this is a bit off-topic.

I'd like to add that some words have a common transliteration, which doesn't really fit the Arabic original.

For example: 
haram I prefere haraam as we have a clear alif after the ra' which means more emphasis.
The same case is with:
halal and halaal, salat is ok but salaat is better, zakat and zakaat.

Also a bit off-topic: I do appreciate your editing efforts, but note, that with 20 or more edits of very old questions we loose the focus for really new questions.